# Error with Quarkus native and JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports, native, quarkus, graalvm

I'm trying to include JasperReports in a Quarkus native service (GraalVM 21.3). After discovering some classes in config files, I can compile and run the app in native mode.

https://es.quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips

However, when I try to load my jrxml in this way:

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jasper/template.jrxml"));
```

This is the error I get:

```
...
023-05-10 13:26:55,789 DEBUG [net.sf.jas.eng.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory] (executor-thread-0) Instantiated SAX parser factory of type com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
2023-05-10 13:26:55,789 DEBUG [net.sf.jas.ext.DefaultExtensionsRegistry] (executor-thread-0) Loading registries for cache key jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@483bf400
LogManager error of type FORMAT_FAILURE: Formatting error
Handler.reportError caught:
```

Yes, nothing else. No trace. Just only that message.

Version of Quarkus: 2.6.0

I have no idea how to solve this problem or where I can find any clue about that error.

Thanks in advance.

Edit (more info):

No stacktrace by default but after overriding this is the trace:

```
Message is Formatting error
Package Name org.jboss.logmanager.handlers
ClassName org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:528)
java.util.logging.Handler.reportError(Handler.java:18)
org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.reportError(ExtHandler.java:332)
org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:45)
org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:66)
org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publishToNestedHandlers(ExtHandler.java:97)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.logging.QuarkusDelayedHandler.doPublish(QuarkusDelayedHandler.java:80)
org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:66)
org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:334)
org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:341)
org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:341)
org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:341)
org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:341)
org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:341)
org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:341)
org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:750)
org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.log(Logger.java:708)
org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerLogger.doLogf(JBossLogManagerLogger.java:53)
org.jboss.logging.Logger.errorf(Logger.java:1743)
io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusErrorHandler.handle(QuarkusErrorHandler.java:127)
io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusErrorHandler.handle(QuarkusErrorHandler.java:30)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleFailure(RouteState.java:1199)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:160)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:201)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handleFailure(RouterImpl.java:253)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleFailure(RouteState.java:1199)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:160)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.doFail(RoutingContextImpl.java:604)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.fail(RoutingContextImpl.java:192)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.fail(RoutingContextImpl.java:181)
io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.fail(RoutingContextWrapper.java:100)
io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:158)
io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:91)
io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:600)
com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
Code is 5
```

After overriding org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler:

```
RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: %s
023-05-10 13:26:55,789 DEBUG [net.sf.jas.eng.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory] (executor-thread-0) Instantiated SAX parser factory of type com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
2023-05-10 13:26:55,789 DEBUG [net.sf.jas.ext.DefaultExtensionsRegistry] (executor-thread-0) Loading registries for cache key 
jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@483bf400
RoutingContext failure (500)
HTTP Request to %s failed, error id: %s
io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusErrorHandler
LogManager error of type FORMAT_FAILURE: Formatting error
Handler.reportError caught:
```

Comment: What does the entire stacktrace look like?

Comment: @geoand no trace by default, but I add more information. Thx

Comment: No ideas from my side unfortunately

Comment: Don't worry, thx again!!. Anyway I've added a complete stacktrace now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this resource is included in native image?

https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips

> For instance, having the following properties in your application.properties:

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes=foo/**,bar/**/*.txt
quarkus.native.resources.excludes=foo/private/**
```

will include:

```
all files in the foo/ directory and its subdirectories except for files in foo/private/ and its subdirectories,

all text files in the bar/ directory and its subdirectories.
```

Comment: Hi. Yes. Finally, I've discovered most of the Jasper classes , the resources and the interfaces I need and I was able to print a "blank" PDF. So it's a big step. I suppose that the solution is to discover all the resources you need.